# "Unexpected var" error while defining variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a very simple popup/modalbox. I wanted to show it after clicking `.openModal` button and to close it by clicking on `.closeModal` or anywhere on the screen. The problem is i cant define the variable that would show if modal is opened(true) or closed(false).

What is the problem?

```
<div class="modal"></div>
   <div class="modalContent">
   <span class="closeModal">x</span>
   </div>

    <script>
        var openModal = false;

        $(".openModal").click(function(){
            $(".modal").show();
            $(".modalContent").show();
             openModal = true;
        })

         $(".closeModal").on('click', function(){
            $(".modal").hide();
            $(".modalContent").hide();
             openModal = false;
        })

        $("body").on('click', function(){
        if(openModal){
            $(".modal").hide();
            $(".modalContent").hide();
        }
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: What's the line above `var ...`?

Comment: can you post all your code ?

Comment: this script is at the bottom of body, so above this line is the rest of the page. First thing above is the modal content div

Comment: you should put that if in a function and call it from the click functions

Comment: Put your code inside ready finction.

Comment: Wrap your code inside a function and call it in document ready.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved it this way:

```
<div class="modal"></div>
<div class="modalContent">
<span class="closeModal">x</span>
</div>

            var openModal = false;

            $("body").on('click','.modal', function(){
                    if(openModal === true){
                        $(".modal").hide();
                        $(".modalContent").hide();
                    }
            });

            $("body").on('click', '.openModal', function(){
                $(".modal").show();
                $(".modalContent").show();
                 openModal = true;       
            });

             $('body').on('click',".closeModal", function(){
                $(".modal").hide();
                $(".modalContent").hide();
                 openModal = false;
            });
```

`.modal` is a grey background that appears while the popup is open and it is fullscreen, so clicking on it works the same as you would click on body. It seems like the body element could not be clicked, like it was behind something. Im not sure

Answer (score 1):

Create a function for the variable check:

```
function checkOpen() {
    if (!openModal) {
        $(".modal").hide();
        $(".modalContent").hide();
    }
}
```

And then call it whenever you modify the modal:

```
$(".openModal").click(function(){
    $(".modal").show();
    $(".modalContent").show();
    openModal = true;
    checkOpen();
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed `!` before the variable name. As to the problem in the title, there is no reason for that to happen with the excerpt he pasted in his question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data-*` attributes in `.modal` :

```
<div class="modal" data-open='false'></div>
```

Then update it in JS :

```
$(".openModal").click(function(){
    $(".modal").show();
    $(".modalContent").show();
    $(".modal").data('open', true);
})

$(".closeModal").on('click', function(){
    $(".modal").hide();
    $(".modalContent").hide();
    $(".modal").data('open', false);
})

$("body").on('click', function(){
    if($(".modal").data('open')){
        $(".modal").hide();
        $(".modalContent").hide();
    }
})
```

Hope this helps.